# Problems with plt.grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

The problem is that the grid in the following plot can only be seen with an un-eaven number of "Numbers" inside each array, inside the matrix.
Any advice to solve this problem is much appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
def gradesPlot(grades):
  for i in range(np.size(grades[0,:])):
    x = 1+i
    y=grades[:,i]
    interval = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,np.size(grades[:,i]))

    plt.title('Grades per assignment')
    plt.ylabel('Grades')
    #plt.grid()
    plt.xticks([n for n in range(np.size(grades[0,:])+1)], ['Assignment%i' %n for n in range(np.size(grades[0,:])+1)],rotation=8)  
    plt.ylim([-3,12])
    plt.autoscale(tight=True)
    plt.scatter(x+interval, y+interval)

 gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,7,4,-3],[7,9,10,12,-3],[2,4,7,10,-3]]))
 #gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,7,4],[7,9,10,12]]))  
 #gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,-3],[7,9,-3],[2,4,10]]))
```

Comment: What you mean with: "with an un-eaven number of "Numbers" inside each array, inside the matrix."?? Can you describe better waht is the problem? And provide a desire output?

Comment: each array has an un-eaven size 
gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,7,4,-3],[7,9,10,12,-3],[2,4,7,10,-3]]))

If you give the function
gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,7,4],[7,9,10,12],[2,4,7,10]])) 
as an input it shows a plot without grid.

And if you give the function
gradesPlot(np.array([[12,4,7,4,-3],[7,9,10,12,-3],[2,4,7,10,-3]])) 
as an input is shows a plot with grid.

Comment: add this code to question - it will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

[`plt.grid()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.grid) does not do what you think it does. Use `plt.grid(True)` instead.

Also all the calls to `plt` methods except `scatter` should be out of the for loop. You only have one title, no need to set it so many times.